# Real Time Multiplayer for iOS using cocos 2dx

Tags: ios, cocos2d-x, game-center, multiplayer

i am developing `iOS` multiplayer game in real time environment, after searching i have some option to use `AppWrap`, `Game Play Google Services` & `RakNet`, can you please suggest which one i should use ? as its purely for the `iOS`.  I am developing it in `cocos 2dx`

Answer (score 0):

try this: this is simple tutorial showing use of game center
http://www.raywenderlich.com/60980/game-center-tutorial-how-to-make-a-simple-multiplayer-game-with-sprite-kit-part-1